# Etherscan Yellow Exclamation Sign - Compiler Specific Version Warning

Tags: etherscan

I just noticed that my contract 0xa150Db9b1Fa65b44799d4dD949D922c0a33Ee606 has the warning on Etherscan (yellow exclamation). This is in the Contract section and the contract has been successfully verified. Could you please advise if this is a serious issue?

Compiler specific version warnings:

The compiled contract might be susceptible to ImplicitConstructorCallvalueCheck (very low-severity), TupleAssignmentMultiStackSlotComponents (very low-severity), MemoryArrayCreationOverflow (low-severity), privateCanBeOverridden (low-severity), SignedArrayStorageCopy (low/medium-severity), ABIEncoderV2StorageArrayWithMultiSlotElement (low-severity), DynamicConstructorArgumentsClippedABIV2 (very low-severity) Solidity Compiler Bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan list the know bugs with the compiler used for your deployment. I let you judge of the possible impacts for your contract but all the bugs are `low` or `medium-severity`. If your ERC20 doesn't do anything fancy you should be safe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer. I really appreciate that!